# How can I save two logos for a custom theme?

Tags: 8, forms

I need to save two custom logos in a custom theme and use them on the site. Can I somehow create a custom field in theme settings or maybe save the path to another logo in one of the .yml theme files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created theme-settings.php in custom theme root, there created new function, it renders new fieldset and a `managed_file` field

```
function theme_name_form_system_theme_settings_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['options_settings'] = [
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Theme Specific Settings'),
  ];

  $form['options_settings']['add_logo'] = [
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Additional logo'),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://logo/',
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('add_logo'),
    '#states' => [
      'visible' => [
        ':input[name="File_type"]' => ['value' => t('Upload Your File')],
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```